# Has anyone implemented a job chain visualizer in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, jobs, chain

Our company relies heavily (unfortunately) on job chains as a big part of our revenue is generating reports for clients. Often times support is left to dig through SQL Server job logs to piece together these chains as there is no formal document detailing each chain.

I would like to create a C# application to query SQL Server and obtain each job and attempt to link them together based upon command steps and build a chart displaying each chain.

Has anyone attempted this and can provide issues they ran into/caveats in doing so? Do you think a recursive sorting algorithm would be useful in determining which jobs in fact call each other?

Another point is these job chains often times exist across multiple servers.

Comment: I've wanted to do this so many times. How are your jobs chained anyway? using a `sp_start_job` step? I'm constantly disappointed by the enhancements to SQL Agent each release of SQL Server - i.e. NONE. At least let us nest jobs in folders!

Comment: Just for your information, SSIS 2012+ has this exact functionality - such as displaying "the details of the completed [SSIS package] executions that have occurred in the past 24 hours" in the [Integration Services Dashboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213362.aspx)

Comment: To respond to the initial comment, yea we almost exclusively use sp_start_job by job name to chain our jobs together.  So in theory that name in the job step should match the next job in line and after acquiring all the jobs across the servers and iterating through them you could "chain" them together based upon that.  Unfortunately our servers are still running mostly 2005 and 2008..  I'm trying to determine a good algorithm for matching job steps, probably a modified sorting algorithm.